Error when trying to modify Azure Event Grid Subscription which was created by enabling Microsoft Defender on Blob Storage
I have enabled Microsoft Defender for Cloud for Storage Account with Malware scanning.

This performs a full malware scan on uploaded content. Some of my Blob Containers are used by Application background processes as lease containers, so the data in those is continuously reuploaded. This causes unwanted costs because Malware scanning uses the beneath feature called Blob index tags for tagging scanned files. When the file is continuously reuploaded attaching Blob index tags is performed again and again.


Scanning is performed using Event Grid Subscription which I found under Storage Account Events blade. It was automatically generated when I enabled Malware Scanning in Microsoft Defender for Cloud panel.
The solution I figured out is to add Advanced Filter to the Event Grid Subscription that will filter out lease containers.

Here comes the issue, when I tried to Save changes in Event Subscription I got information that Deployment was failed due to error that subscriber user is not in the same tenant as the webhook AAD Application.


Could you confirm whether the signed-in user is part of same tenant as webhook aad application or guest user?
